# mean diagonal minus one

Tags: r, matrix, diagonal

Is it possible to calculate the mean for the diagonal line one under the matrix diagonal?

```
    a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
a1  0   1   1   1   1
a2  2   0   1   1   1
a3  1   3   0   1   1
a4  1   1   4   0   1
a5  1   1   1   5   0
```

I want to calculate the mean of 2+3+4+5

Comment: Is it always one line under the diagonal? Or should it be generalizable?

Comment: could be generalized to apply to either the upper or lower line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possibility

```
mean(m[col(m) == (row(m) - 1)])
## [1] 3.5
```

The idea here is to get the column and row indices and then select only the values when *column == row - 1* (just below the diagonal- as the diagonal is *col == row*)

---

**Data**

```
m <- structure(c(0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"), c("a1", 
"a2", "a3", "a4", "a5")))
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes. I think (as always in R) there are various ways to do it, but here is one. It uses the `diag` function from base-R and removes the first row and last column before getting the diagonal and calculating it's mean.

```
res <- mean(diag(mm[-1,-ncol(mm)]))
```

Data used:

```
mm <- structure(c(0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"), c("a1", 
"a2", "a3", "a4", "a5")))
```